# How do I compress repeating tkinter code into a loop so it displays rectangles without having to write out each individual rectangle's coordinates?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code that repeats that I would like to compress into a loop somehow. The code is meant to show a series of rectangles that change color when your mouse hovers over them, and because I have numerous rectangles, all of the code repeating is the same except for 2 coordinates for the location of my rectangles. Therefore, I want to somehow compress the following code into a loop:

```
from tkinter import *

c=Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg="White")

c.create_rectangle(50,50,70,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(90,50,110,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(130,50,150,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(170,50,190,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(210,50,230,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(250,50,270,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(290,50,310,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(330,50,350,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(370,50,390,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(410,50,430,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(450,50,470,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.create_rectangle(490,50,510,150,outline="Blue",
                   width=2,fill="Gray",activefill="Red")
c.pack()
mainloop()
```

My first idea to approaching this was setting the original rectangle dimensions to (x, 50, y, 150), setting x=50 and y=70, and then somehow incorporating that while x<=490 and y<=510, x=x+40. However, I don't know how to incorporate all of this into a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the alteration you are looking for using a `while` loop:

```
from tkinter import *

c = Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg="White")
cords = [50, 50, 70, 150]

while cords[0] <= 490 and cords[2] <= 510:
    c.create_rectangle(cords, outline="Blue", width=2, fill="Gray", activefill="Red")
    cords[0] += 40
    cords[2] += 40

c.pack()
mainloop()
```

Comment: I really like this answer - very clean and readable! but what if the user wants to add more rectangles? They'd have to calculate the final offsets for the `while` conditions ahead of time! (not a huge deal, but flexible code is always a good idea) :)

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I tried to keep it simple and only include what they asked for: ```while``` loop and the bounds. I suppose I could have created a x_max and y_max variable. (as I am not sure if they wanted a numbered amount of rectangles or to repeat until hitting a limit)

Comment: No worries - this is a nice solution! It should be easy enough to adapt to a less hard-coded version.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `for` loop, using some math to update the offsets each iteration since they always change by the same amount

```
c = Canvas(width=800, height=600, bg="White")

# 'range(12)' returns a sequence of 12 numbers, from 0 to 11
# you can iterate over that sequence with a for loop
for i in range(12):
    # calculate offsets
    x1 = (40 * (i + 1) + 10)
    x2 = (40 * (i + 1) + 30)
    # create a tuple of coordinates
    coords = (x1, 50, x2, 150)
    # create a rectangle with the appropriate coordinates
    c.create_rectangle(coords, outline="Blue", width=2, fill="Gray", activefill="Red")
```

Note that I'm adding 1 to the value of `i` because `range` iterables start at 0